# submit button with no form filling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

Hi i want a button to be shown on all my pages. 
that code should be in such a way that no form filling is needed

> > the text on button will be "Problem? Click Here"
> >     when click on button, it will be pressed and the person who has clicked cannot click again unless reload the page.
> >     After the button is clicked the mail should be sent to admin with the exact link of page where button was clicked.
> >     there should be no form to fill.
> >     As for example facebook like button like the content meanwhile its pressed.
> >     What should be the code for this? Any suggestion please?
> >     Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? As far as i know SO is not the place where people code for you on demand..

Comment: You have confused SO with Elance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML button element with an onclick javascript function linked to it.

Since you don't want the button to work again until you have reloaded the page, you will need to do this through AJAX. This means you will have to send a request to the server, where, for instance, a PHP script will retrieve the page name from a GET variable and send the email to the administrator. The javascript part can keep track of the button being clicked once or not.

That should give you some pointers on where to start with your code. However, as stated in direct comments to your question, this site is not meant for asking for coding work to be done for you. Perhaps next time, try to think of a possible solution and ask for advice on your solution (improvements, coding conventions, etc)